# ggplot2: how to customize color and shape of points?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a stripchart using `ggplot2`. Below is a subset of `tbl` which has the relevant columns I am using, along with a `dput`.

```
> tbl[,c('Study_ID', 'Probe_ID', 'Group1','Group2','LogFC', 'adj_P_Value', 'P_Value', 'CI_L','CI_R','Disease')]
   Study_ID  Probe_ID               Group1                   Group2       LogFC  adj_P_Value      P_Value        CI_L        CI_R
1   GSE2461 220307_at                 Male                   Female -0.09017596 1.000000e+00 5.662047e-01 -0.43955752  0.25920561
2   GSE2461 220307_at   ulcerative colitis irritable bowel syndrome  0.08704844 1.000000e+00 5.784053e-01 -0.26134341  0.43544028
3  GSE27887 220307_at     nonlesional skin            lesional skin -0.03501474 1.000000e+00 4.409881e-01 -0.12677636  0.05674688
4  GSE27887 220307_at         pretreatment            posttreatment  0.01096914 1.000000e+00 8.080366e-01 -0.08064105  0.10257932
5  GSE42296   7921677           Infliximab         Before treatment -0.03707265 1.000000e+00 3.979403e-01 -0.12407201  0.04992672
6  GSE42296   7921677            Responder             Nonresponder  0.07644834 1.000000e+00 1.505444e-01 -0.02849309  0.18138977
7  GSE42296   7921677 Rheumatoid Arthritis          Crohn's Disease  0.42318863 3.960125e-06 1.989713e-10  0.31076269  0.53561457
8  GSE58558 220307_at                    M                        F -0.11881801 1.000000e+00 1.130180e-01 -0.26629675  0.02866072
9  GSE58558 220307_at    non lesional skin            lesional skin -0.18914128 1.000000e+00 3.696739e-03 -0.31525660 -0.06302596
10 GSE58558 220307_at            responder             nonresponder -0.14470319 1.000000e+00 2.328062e-01 -0.38396386  0.09455748
11 GSE58558 220307_at              week 12                    day 1 -0.39619004 4.311942e-01 2.215798e-05 -0.57226227 -0.22011781
12 GSE58558 220307_at               week 2                    day 1 -0.28765455 1.000000e+00 8.753977e-04 -0.45375957 -0.12154953
13 GSE59294 220307_at   C Dupilumab 300 mg       B Dupilumab 150 mg  0.16853309 1.000000e+00 1.140155e-01 -0.04273877  0.37980494
14 GSE59294 220307_at            D Placebo       B Dupilumab 150 mg -0.18995566 1.000000e+00 2.264691e-01 -0.50367856  0.12376724
15 GSE59294 220307_at              NL skin                  LS skin  0.01376129 1.000000e+00 9.041383e-01 -0.21711706  0.24463964
16 GSE59294 220307_at                  Pre                     Post  0.02234607 1.000000e+00 8.069367e-01 -0.16235054  0.20704268
                                        Disease
1  irritable bowel syndrome; ulcerative colitis
2  irritable bowel syndrome; ulcerative colitis
3                             atopic Dermatitis
4                             atopic Dermatitis
5         Crohn's Disease; Rheumatoid Arthritis
6         Crohn's Disease; Rheumatoid Arthritis
7         Crohn's Disease; Rheumatoid Arthritis
8                             Atopic Dermatitis
9                             Atopic Dermatitis
10                            Atopic Dermatitis
11                            Atopic Dermatitis
12                            Atopic Dermatitis
13                            atopic Dermatitis
14                            atopic Dermatitis
15                            atopic Dermatitis
16                            atopic Dermatitis
```

Here is the `dput` :

```
> dput(droplevels(tbl[,c('Study_ID', 'Probe_ID', 'Group1','Group2','LogFC', 'adj_P_Value', 'P_Value', 'CI_L','CI_R','Disease')]))
structure(list(Study_ID = c("GSE2461", "GSE2461", "GSE27887", 
"GSE27887", "GSE42296", "GSE42296", "GSE42296", "GSE58558", "GSE58558", 
"GSE58558", "GSE58558", "GSE58558", "GSE59294", "GSE59294", "GSE59294", 
"GSE59294"), Probe_ID = c("220307_at", "220307_at", "220307_at", 
"220307_at", "7921677", "7921677", "7921677", "220307_at", "220307_at", 
"220307_at", "220307_at", "220307_at", "220307_at", "220307_at", 
"220307_at", "220307_at"), Group1 = c("Male", "ulcerative colitis", 
"nonlesional skin", "pretreatment", "Infliximab", "Responder", 
"Rheumatoid Arthritis", "M", "non lesional skin", "responder", 
"week 12", "week 2", "C Dupilumab 300 mg", "D Placebo", "NL skin", 
"Pre"), Group2 = c("Female", "irritable bowel syndrome", "lesional skin", 
"posttreatment", "Before treatment", "Nonresponder", "Crohn's Disease", 
"F", "lesional skin", "nonresponder", "day 1", "day 1", "B Dupilumab 150 mg", 
"B Dupilumab 150 mg", "LS skin", "Post"), LogFC = c(-0.0901759558643281, 
0.0870484364429408, -0.0350147376937934, 0.0109691380052655, 
-0.0370726462749328, 0.0764483363743359, 0.423188628619509, -0.118818013184408, 
-0.189141277685995, -0.144703191279992, -0.396190039768736, -0.28765454670704, 
0.168533085440721, -0.189955660434197, 0.0137612879743023, 0.0223460675171673
), adj_P_Value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3.96012504622782e-06, 1, 
1, 1, 0.431194244819507, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), P_Value = c(0.566204678925109, 
0.578405275354266, 0.440988072013756, 0.808036622723435, 0.397940346528484, 
0.150544373610059, 1.98971262936634e-10, 0.11301796668591, 0.00369673863311212, 
0.232806229179741, 2.21579776371792e-05, 0.000875397680320129, 
0.114015475901252, 0.226469133014055, 0.904138332714553, 0.806936684043586
), CI_L = c(-0.439557521861354, -0.261343410788222, -0.12677635951562, 
-0.0806410486876688, -0.124072011981945, -0.0284930943795223, 
0.310762687356251, -0.26629674914578, -0.315256597358499, -0.383963864121397, 
-0.57226227039893, -0.453759565458485, -0.0427387734415052, -0.503678563834605, 
-0.217117064412363, -0.162350541147386), CI_R = c(0.259205610132698, 
0.435440283674103, 0.0567468841280329, 0.1025793246982, 0.0499267194320791, 
0.181389767128194, 0.535614569882768, 0.0286607227769647, -0.0630259580134921, 
0.0945574815614131, -0.220117809138542, -0.121549527955595, 0.379804944322947, 
0.12376724296621, 0.244639640360967, 0.207042676181721), Disease = c("irritable bowel syndrome; ulcerative colitis", 
"irritable bowel syndrome; ulcerative colitis", "atopic Dermatitis", 
"atopic Dermatitis", "Crohn's Disease; Rheumatoid Arthritis", 
"Crohn's Disease; Rheumatoid Arthritis", "Crohn's Disease; Rheumatoid Arthritis", 
"Atopic Dermatitis", "Atopic Dermatitis", "Atopic Dermatitis", 
"Atopic Dermatitis", "Atopic Dermatitis", "atopic Dermatitis", 
"atopic Dermatitis", "atopic Dermatitis", "atopic Dermatitis"
)), .Names = c("Study_ID", "Probe_ID", "Group1", "Group2", "LogFC", 
"adj_P_Value", "P_Value", "CI_L", "CI_R", "Disease"), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Finally, here the code that I have so far.

```
#test using ggplot2
maxFC = max(as.numeric(as.character(tbl$LogFC)))
minFC = min(as.numeric(as.character(tbl$LogFC)))


datasetList = tbl$Study_ID
hLines =(which(duplicated(datasetList) == FALSE) - 0.5)


tbl$ylab <- paste(tbl$Group2," \U2192 ","\n", tbl$Group1, sep = "")


p <- ggplot(data = tbl, aes(x = LogFC, y = Probe_ID, group = Study_ID)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log(0.5,2), size = 0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log(2/3,2), size = 0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log(1.5,2), size = 0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log(2,2), size = 0.2) +
  labs(title = tbl$gene, y = "Contrasts", x = bquote(~Log[2]~'(Fold Change)')) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(x = LogFC, xmin =  CI_L, xmax = CI_R), height = .1) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = cut(adj_P_Value, c(-Inf, 0.01, 0.05, Inf)))) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "P Value",
                     values = c("(-Inf,0.01]" = "red",
                                "(0.01,0.05)" = "orange",
                                "(0.05, Inf]" = "black"),
                     labels = c("<= 0.01", "0.01 < P Value <= 0.05", "> 0.05")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c( 4,15,19)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(-2,minFC),max(2,maxFC))) +

  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 180),
        #panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        #panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        #panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white'),
        #panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0.5,'lines'),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  facet_grid(Study_ID+ylab~ ., scales = 'free', space = 'free', switch = 'both')


p
```

Basically, the points actual position is determined via their `LogFC` value, but  the points that have an `adj_P_Value <= 0.01` should be displayed as red circles, in between 0.01 and 0.05 as orange squares, and `>= 0.05` as black crosses (i.e. the data that I've provided shouldn't show any squares). My attempt as this was using `cut` in the `geom_point`but this doesn't seem to work. The colors are showing up correct, but the shapes are not.  This has been bugging me for a while. If there's any conventions or standards that I'm breaking (which I probably am), please let me know and suggest something that would achieve exactly what I have already. Thanks!

**Update**:

```
#test using ggplot2
maxFC = max(as.numeric(as.character(tbl$LogFC)))
minFC = min(as.numeric(as.character(tbl$LogFC)))

datasetList = tbl$Study_ID
hLines =(which(duplicated(datasetList) == FALSE) - 0.5)


tbl$ylab <- paste(tbl$Group2," \U2192 ","\n", tbl$Group1, sep = "")

tbl <- tbl %>% 
  mutate(colourgroup = case_when(
    .$adj_P_Value <= 0.01 ~ 1,
    .$adj_P_Value > 0.01 & .$adj_P_Value < 0.05 ~ 2,
    .$adj_P_Value >= 0.05 ~ 3
     ) )

p <- ggplot(data = tbl, aes(x = LogFC, y = Probe_ID, colour = colourgroup, shape = colourgroup)) +
  #geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log(0.5,2), size = 0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log(2/3,2), size = 0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log(1.5,2), size = 0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log(2,2), size = 0.2) +
  labs(title = tbl$gene, y = "Contrasts", x = bquote(~Log[2]~'(Fold Change)')) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(x = LogFC, xmin =  CI_L, xmax = CI_R), height = .1) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(c('red','orange','black')) +
  scale_shape_manual(c(19,15,4))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(-2,minFC),max(2,maxFC))) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 180),
        #panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        #panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        #panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white'),
        #panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0.5,'lines'),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  facet_grid(Study_ID+ylab~ ., scales = 'free', space = 'free', switch = 'both')


p
```

Comment: if the answer below was helpful please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark to the left. This lets the community know that the issue is closed. If it wasn't helpful, no worries

Answer (score 1):

Add a column of the factor you want

```
library(dplyr)
tbl <- tbl %>% 
         mutate(colourgroup = case_when(
                                   adj_P_Value <= 0.01 ~ 1,
                                   adj_P_Value > 0.01 & adj_P_Value < 0.05 ~ 2,
                                   adj_P_Value >= 0.05 ~ 3 ))
```

Then change

```
aes(x = LogFC, y = Probe_ID, group = Study_ID)
```

To

```
aes(x = LogFC, y = Probe_ID, colour = factor(colourgroup), shape = factor(colourgroup))
```

And

```
scale_color_manual(values=c("red","orange","black")) +
scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,2,3))
```

## MINIMAL EXAMPLE

This minimal `ggplot` command worked for me. Note I switched the `x` and `y` values on purpose, and `red` and `orange` can be difficult to distinguish

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = Probe_ID, y=LogFC, colour=factor(colourgroup), shape=factor(colourgroup))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","orange","black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,2,3))
```

Comment: Then I would be free to delete `geom_point` and two `scale_*` lines, correct?

Comment: Also, what is `TRUE ~ as.character(x)` doing?

Comment: Getting error on the `TRUE ~ as.factor(x)` saying "object 'x' not found"

Comment: See my edit.. I am getting an error "Continuous value supplied to discrete scale" at some point in `ggplot()`

Comment: Weird, still giving me same error. Your code is exactly as I have in the UPDATE aside from the `values =c(..)` in the scale_* functions?

Comment: Interesting that it changes the color of the `errorbarh()` as well. But still showing some weird behavior. For your minimal example, if `df2` is the same as my `tbl`, and you change to `scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,15,4))`, it _should_ be displaying mostly black crosses. Even though the `colourgroup` column is correct (3 for most rows, 1 for one row), it is not mapping properly.

Comment: At the risk of opening up another question for a small addition, do you know how I would update this so that it plots in descending order according to logFC? I've tried variations of `reorder()` and using `arrange` from `dplyr` but can't get it.

Comment: It would probably easier opening a new question. First, it separates problems so that the community has a better chance of finding solutions to similar questions. Second, I'd have to see what you've tried.

Comment: new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576384/ploting-stripchart-with-descending-order-of-logfc-values-ggplot

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look